# Downgrade Mozilla Firefox and Thunderbird to versions used in 18.04

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, mozilla

Well, I moved to 19.10 and new Firefox and Thunderbird stopped reading my profiles.

Since I have quite a lot of data in these profiles I would like to continue using it and I want to downgrade both Firefox and Thunderbird.

How can I do it?

**EDIT:** Actually I installed fresh Ubuntu 19.10 and copied my profile data from previous version. Until this method worked for ~8 years.

Comment: When you say 'upgraded', how?  As Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has two tested & supported upgrade paths, one to 18.10, and the other which doesn't yet exist, but will be to 20.04 when 20.04.1 is released. Did you re-install? or go outside of tested/supported upgrades thus possibly created issues?  The versions if firefox differ little between releases (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=firefox)

Comment: @guiverc Please see the edit.

Comment: Have you copied them to the ***correct*** `~/.mozilla/firefox/????????.default/`  and `~/.thunderbird/????????.default/` directories while Firefox and Thunderbird were not running.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli These files were the only ones. And yes nor Firefox or Thunderbird were running.